# Is there a way to check if a user has really rated your app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm writing a WP7 application and I have code to ask the user for a marketplace review every five runs with an exponential back off so it is less annoying.  If the user clicks 'ok' on my "would you like to review" message box, I launch the review task and I store that the user has reviewed the application so I don't ask again.

```
var marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["HasReviewed"] = true;
```

However, while it's *likely* they did rate the app, I'm actually not a 100% sure they did.  Is there a way to check if the current user really has written a review?  Does the MarketplaceReviewTask() have a returnvalue?  I haven't been able to find anything that indicates I can listen for it.

Comment: I'd imagine no, seems like an invasion of privacy. Just take their word for it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `MarketplaceReviewTask` does not have any events which return a value. A case with most of the `Launcher` tasks. `Chooser` tasks have events to collect the information. Like @willmel said in the comment, it does look like an invasion of privacy.

Comment: Thanks abhinav and @willmenl for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a check which will check locally if user has rated the application earlier or not. Take a look at following code:

```
public void reviewfunction()
    {
        //For Windows phone 8 app
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        //For windows phone 8.1 app or universal app use the following line of code
        //var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        //set the app name
        string Appname = "My app";

        if (!settings.Contains("review"))
        {
            settings.Add("review", 1);
            settings.Add("rcheck", 0);
        }
        else
        {
            int no = Convert.ToInt32(settings["review"]);
            int check = Convert.ToInt32(settings["rcheck"]);
            no++;
            if ((no == 4 || no == 7 || no % 10 == 0) && check == 0)
            {
                settings["review"] = no;
                MessageBoxResult mm = MessageBox.Show("Thank you for using this application.\nWould you like to give some time to rate and review this application to help us improve", Appname, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (mm == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    settings["rcheck"] = 1;
                    MarketplaceReviewTask rr = new MarketplaceReviewTask();
                    rr.Show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                settings["review"] = no;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you. Source code can be downloaded from [here](http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/general/adding-app-review-reminder-in-windows-phone-app-without-using-rate-my-app-toolkit/).