# Rating an app in WP7 app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to check if a user has really rated your app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290199/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-user-has-really-rated-your-app)

I am planning to use a nag screen to get  [my app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/boxit/9196aedf-ef36-41fe-80e5-744b2a86d59e) rated. User can be directed using `MarketplaceReviewTask`. But how to know if user has rated the app, so that i can stop nag screen from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

User will returned automatically to your app after reviewing.

Comment: user can return using back button without rating