# Way to check if user actually rates application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, review

When the user is hinted to rate the application using tasks, is there any way that I can check whether the user actually rated the app? Or had just exit the marketplace before rating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. I assume you are using the MarketPlaceReviewTask class? If so, the only method you really have available is .Show() which does not have a return. There is also another SO question about this as well which has the same conclusion: [Is there a way to check if a user has really rated your app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290199/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-user-has-really-rated-your-app)

Here is a link to the MSDN reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.marketplacereviewtask(v=vs.105).aspx